# How to use ssl certificate in uwp

Tags: c#, ssl, uwp

I using my test certificate in uwp. I'm not sure where is wrong, so that's why I'm here.

My steps:

1, open Package.appxmanifest, go to Capabilities, check Shared User Certificates.

2, go to Declarations, select Certificates and add it. On the right area, Click Add New, in Store name field, I selected Trusted Root Certifacte Authorities(In fact, I dont know this field mean, and which one to choose). In Content field, I select my pfx/p12 file.

3, In mainpage.xaml.cs,

```
StorageFile certificateFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"client.p12");
        IBuffer certificateBuffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(certificateFile);
        string encodedCertificate = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(certificateBuffer);
        await CertificateEnrollmentManager.ImportPfxDataAsync(encodedCertificate, "000000", ExportOption.NotExportable, KeyProtectionLevel.NoConsent, InstallOptions.None, "Client Certificate");

        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
        handler.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12 | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls11 | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls;
        handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
            (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) =>
            {
                return true;
            };

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
        //HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://test.client.ssl/");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://192.168.101.99/");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string temp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

4, build & run.

I got error:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073CF6] AppxManifest.xml (41,10): 
Error 0x80092009: Unable to register b17011a8-22d6-4a6a-bdb9-4a42390c9639_1.0.0.0_x86__701p3ryg2e8g6 package, 
because trying to open and evaluate the client. When adding a p12 certificate to the root store, 
I encountered the following error: The requested object could not be found.
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalllllllllllllllllllllllllllllly, I worked it out.
The method I import cert file is wrong.
The original method just import cert file to local app, but not send to server.
I changed another way, add cert to `HttpClientHandler`.

```
X509Certificate2 cer = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes("client.pfx"), "000000");
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cer);
```

Then in Declarations, click the remove button at the right area.

Then Done!!!

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, the application seems does not find your certificate file. Please follow the steps below:

1. In `Solution Explorer`, right-click your `client.p12` file, choose the `Properties`
2. Set `Build Action` to `Content`.

---

**Update**

The test certificate may not be recognized correctly. I made the following attempt:

1. Generate the side load package of the application, and get the `.cer` certificate from the side loading package.
2. Use cer certificate instead of pfx/p12 certificate, the app can run normally

From your usage, you want to use the certificate to initiate a network security request, but this does not seem to use the `Certification` extension. This is a [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/share-certificates#create-a-uwp-app-that-uses-certificate-authentication) on how to initiate a network security request. It can be used as a reference.

Best regards.

Comment: Hi, I already set it as Content and copy if newer. Is there anything wrong I did above the steps? Thx.

Comment: Although I get data from successfully, but I still can't understand the difference between `Import cert to app` and `Send cert via HttpClientHandler`. I used `Send cert via HttpClientHandler`, it works. Following the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/share-certificates#create-a-uwp-app-that-uses-certificate-authentication), it seems same to my original method.

Comment: Hi, Glad to see you solved the problem. Introduce a certificate, this operation is not a problem in itself, but you may not use the `Certificate` extension, which is not necessary for network secure requests.

Comment: Pardon me, what does `Certificate` extension means, and which part of code refers to extension. Thx.

Comment: It's the `Declarations` in your `package.appxmanifest`, you used the `Certificate` in it.

Comment: Ok, got it. But what does the `Store name` and `Content` mean. Thx

Comment: `Store name` refers to where the certificate is stored. When you double-click the certificate import, the import program will let you choose a storage location. It's like you put different files in different folders. `Content` refers to the certificate file

Comment: OK, got it. Thanks.